What causes natural part-monsters?
The third season of Sweet Home reveals that part-monsters like Hyun-su and "Ui-myeong"

 (actually Yi-kyung's fiancee)

can come into being either naturally or artificially, and further that every other part-monster, except the two aforementioned, was artificially created using "Ui-myeong's" blood, suggesting that the part-monster transformation is much rarer than it previously seemed.
What causes some very few people to turn into part-monsters instead of fully transforming into monsters?

I suppose Genetic Predisposition, some individuals may have genetic traits that predispose them to partial transformations instead of fully becoming monsters.
also natural part-monsters might result from rare or specific conditions in the transformation process, where the individual's body interacts differently with the monster virus compared to others.
I think that the natural occurrence of part-monsters seems to be influenced by both inherent genetic factors and unique physiological responses to the transformation.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
